# Updating Powerpoint embedded in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a excel file in which 3 Powerpoint presentations are embedded(as object). These are the blank templates of the deck I want to prepare. How can I assign these embedded Powerpoint presentations through VBA. I know that I can keep Powerpoint presentations separately and access them but I want to make them into one file this time. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is not clear at all.  Also, please include what have you tried so far? Please show your code. Here is a hint: embedded OLEOBjects are members of the `Shapes` collection on a `Slide`. They can be accessed by `.Name` or index position.  Note that working with OLEObjects is generally a pretty inefficient way of doing things and they are notoriously difficult to work with.  If I knew more about what you're actually trying to do, I could maybe recommend some alternative...

Comment: Something like this?  You have PPT embedded as an OLE object in your workbook.  You want to use this embedded PPT as the basis for a new presentation you want to create via automation from Excel.  You might be able to Activate the embedded PPT object and tell the ensuing instance of PPT to save the activepresentation under whatever name you like to give you a new PPT presentation to work with.

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming you have a PPT presentation embedded in Excel and its name is "Object 1"

```
Dim oSh As Shape

Set oSh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Object 1")

With oSh
    ' Uncomment the appropriate line for the result you want

    ' Show
    '.OLEFormat.Verb (1)

    ' Edit (in place)
    '.OLEFormat.Verb (2)

    ' Open
    .OLEFormat.Verb (3)

End With
```